# is there an smsMessageTracking to capture email information?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

good afternoon team!

I'm building dataviews to get shipping information through automation for a DE

I managed to create the smsMessageTracking but I would like a model that does the same but to capture information from emails sent as email title, date sent etc.

is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there’s actually plenty information on data views out there. Check out this visual:

[image]

And the article it comes from: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/22/data-views-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/

Plus, the official docs: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&language=en_US&type=5

For email data, you need to look at Sent and Job data views. If you want engagement info as well, look at Open, Click, Bounce and Unsubscribe data views.